# String representation of type in Python

Tags: python

I wish to use a type function in an eval statement, so I need just the string representation of that function. For example:

```
print(type("cow"))
<class 'str'>
```

Here I need it to output 'str'. But when I try:

```
type("cow").__str__()
TypeError: descriptor '__str__' of 'str' object needs an argument
type("cow").__repr__()
TypeError: descriptor '__repr__' of 'str' object needs an argument
```

Curiously, Jupyter notebook prints it correctly if that is the last line in the cell.

Why is this error happening? What is the correct way to obtain just the Type string?

Comment: `print(type("cow").__name__)`

Comment: This looks like XY problem. Better describe what you want to do, because all this is quite strange.

Comment: Agree with buran. This is [very unusual and almost certainly there's a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). `eval` and programmatically checking type are both major red flags.

Comment: Are you talking about the string *"cow"* or some variable *cow* (e.g. `cow = "abc"`)?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. The "cow" is a string as shown in the question. I am not sure what is strange, I want to understand this behavior, and I explained my desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want

```
type("cow").__name__
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Given the question ambiguity, `print(type("cow"))` is kind of misleading. Is ***cow***:

- The **string** *"cow"*
- A variable named *cow* (that by coincidence happens to be a string in this case)

Anyway here's a way that works for both:

> ```py
> >>> cow = "Moo!!"
> >>>
> >>> # Variable
> ...
> >>> cow.__class__.__name__
> 'str'
> >>> # String literal
> ...
> >>> "cow".__class__.__name__
> 'str'
> ```

For more details, check [[Python 3.Docs]: Built-in Types - Special Attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#special-attributes).

Comment: Thank you, this parallel is actually great. I had to accept the other one, because he answered exactly what I asked, but you implicitly answered my why as well.

Comment: Not sure what is ambiguous about the question. The code fragment clearly contains the string "cow".